# How can I see the actual binary content of a VB6 Double variable?

Tags: vb6, internal-representation

I have hunted about quite a bit but can't find a way to get at the Hexadecimal or Binary representation of the content of a Double variable in VB6.  (Are Double variables held in IEEE754 format?)

The provided **Hex(x)** function is no good because it integerizes its input first.
So if I want to see the exact bit pattern produced by Atn(1), **Hex(Atn(1))** does NOT produce it.

I'm trying to build a mathematical function containing If clauses. I want to be able to see that the values returned on either side of these boundaries are, as closely as possible, in line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the debugger not reveal this? (I don't have VB6 installed because it is from ancient times)

Comment: Similar thing for .NET that may be possible/available in VB6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/troubleshooting-data-types. Not the binary representation but if you're only doing mathsy stuff then you _probably_ don't need that, you just need all the precision of the type

Answer (score 3):

Yes, VB6 uses standard IEEE format for `Double`. One way to get what you want without resorting to `memcpy()` tricks is to use two UDTs. The first would contain one `Double`, the second a static array of 8 `Byte`. `LSet` the one containing the `Double` into the one containing the `Byte` array. Then you can examine each `Byte` from the `Double` one by one.

If you need to see code let us know.

[edit]

At the module level:

```
Private byte_result() As Byte

Private Type double_t
    dbl As Double
End Type

Private Type bytes_t
    byts(1 To 8) As Byte
End Type
```

Then:

```
Function DoubleToBytes (aDouble As Double) As Byte()
   Dim d As double_t
   Dim b As bytes_t
   d.dbl = aDouble
   LSet b = d
   DoubleToBytes = b.byts
End Function
```

To use it:

```
Dim Indx As Long

byte_result = DoubleToBytes(12345.6789#)

For Indx = 1 To 8
   Debug.Print Hex$(byte_result(Indx)),
Next
```

This is air code but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Dear Jim, You are way ahead of me!!  :-)  What is a "UDT"?
Would you be able to fill in the code for some such function at the following:-
Public Function DoubleToHex(ByVal D as Double) as String
    ....
    DoubleToHex = ... ' The magic!!  :-)
End Function ' DoubleToHex

Comment: @Wojja62 - I know this isn't exactly what you asked for but it can serve as an example of how to do it.

Comment: UDT: User Defined Type. @JimMack: Great idea. I now remember again, why I liked VB6 so much, and still sad that M$ killed it with the "VB".NET.